# mat-table - overflows parent div if the content of any of the column is very long

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

Using angular material component mat-table and angular flex layout to display a data table inside a div.

stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-af6dyv)

Unable to fix the width of the table inside the div. If any of the column is having longer data, then the table overflows the parent div.

Expected behaviour is to show ellipse for the column with longer data, and the table width should be fixed (100% inside parent div) and not dependent on the column data.

Comment: use this css `.mat-cell, .mat-header-cell {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-break: break-word;
}`

Comment: @BearNithi this fixed the table overflow issue, but it does not give the ellipse to indicate that the content is truncated. It rather breaks the content into multiple lines (sometimes this is not a desired behaviour because there is no control over where the breakage occurs in the data being displayed)

Comment: give css to mat-cell {word-break:break-all;}

Comment: This is a surprisingly difficult problem. Here's an official thread about it https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9874

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Best Solution Is Don't Use Custom CSS

```
Just Replace Your <table></table> Tag with <mat-table></mat-table>
```

[image]

I hope This Will Work For You

Comment: I tried removing all custom CSS and changing table tag to mat-table. The table overflow issue is fixed, but the column data is still overflowing - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-af6dyv-fw6dqs)

Comment: also the vertical alignment of text inside the cells is distorted

Comment: Use The Below Answer CSS  Along With My Answer It Will Solve The Issue  
                                                                                                                      
`.mat-cell, .mat-header-cell { overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; word-break: break-word; }`

Comment: it doesn't fix the vertical alignment of data in the cells. Anyway I was able to fix it with flex-layout-align. But using this will remove the ellipse when the cell data is truncated. So I had to wrap the cell data inside another span having `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;`  -- [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-af6dyv-ewpn4h)

Comment: Dude nice, this was legit my problem.

Comment: In case you're here some year after, this solution does not work anymore